# Apache Pulsar, cannot read value from getCounter() but can read other state values

Tags: java, counter, apache-pulsar

Apache Pulsar function is unable to read a counter value as `context.getCounter()`.

Testing using local machine, single function, and running a tester producer and consumer from CLI. Function is reading subscription and printing it's function name (from context), so it seems it's only having a problem with accessing the counter value.

```
import org.apache.pulsar.functions.api.Context;
import org.apache.pulsar.functions.api.Function;

public class App implements Function<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String process(String input, Context context) {
        System.out.println(context.getFunctionName()); //this works


        context.incrCounter("ABC",1);

        Long n = context.getCounter("ABC");

        System.out.println(context.getCounter("ABC")); //this doesn't

        return n.toString(); //consumer on the topic doesn't get any messages
    }
}
```

(CLI command all on same AWS ec2)

```
bin/pulsar-admin functions localrun \
  --jar /home/ubuntu/population_watch/0_ingestion/pulsar-functions-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  --className xyz.datapipeline.pulsar_functions.App \
  --inputs persistent://public/default/testinput1 \
  --output persistent://public/default/testoutput1 \
  --name myTestFunction
```

(consumer)

```
bin/pulsar-client consume -n 10 -s “test” persistent://public/default/testoutput1
```

(producer)

```
bin/pulsar-client produce -m “Hello” persistent://public/default/testinput1
```

Function should increment counter for key "ABC" by 1 each time a message is sent, and the subsequent `getCounter()` should return the value (i.e. 1... then 2.... then 3... with each message sent by producer).

EDIT: Terminating my AWS instances and re-creating my cluster solved the problem, so it seems it was configuration related.